# Spin Echo Experiment

Tags: experimental-physics

I'm doing an spin echo experiment for different dilutions of Glycerol as an undergraduate physics lab experiment. At the end of my experiment I will need to extend it and do some initiatives! I have a few potential extensions in mind. But I was wondering what other cool stuff one can do with typical equipments for such experiments (I've got things like giant magnets, RF oscillators, probes and other measuring devices, etc)

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate a bit on your experiment and the potential extensions. You can try different substances, look at temperature dependencies, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could try bilateral experiments opposed to mechanical ones which are more fun if you into watching things happen by themselves without computing the control mechanisms. Start with some type of "conversion plane" which could be any material that interacts with the experimental magnets, then modify the levels of planar differentials according to the most dependent part which is finding properties with patterns that respond, also adjusting the plane could be difficult.